# В IE8 jQuery не работает. Почему?

Tags: jquery

Мне интересно, почему не работает?

Comment: с чего вы взяли? Вот только что проверил - работает

Comment: ну это еще не значит, что jQuery не работает с IE. Это может означать что угодно. Например, что в вашем коде ошибка.

Comment: кстати, а какая у вас версия jQuery?

Comment: Отладчик показывает что функцию setInterval не поддерживает. Последняя версия на данный момент

Comment: а какое отношение имеет setInterval к JQuery? Это стандартная функция JavaScript'a, а не jQuery

Comment: как вариант используйте другую версию jquery - например 1.7.2

Answer (score 5):

Проблема может быть в том, что jQuery начиная с версии 2.0 отказалась от поддержки IE 8 (дескать, это позволило уменьшить объем  библиотеки, но скорее всего этот IE просто всех задолбал).  Список поддерживаемых браузеров можно увидеть на [офф. сайте](http://jquery.com/browser-support/). Впрочем, если у вас в IE 8 не работает setInterval, то виновата в этом не jQuery, поскольку setInterval - это функция чистого JS

Comment: а что посоветуете?

Comment: либо юзать версии ниже 2.0, либо забить на IE < 9.0 (что в общем-то не так уж критично - подстраиваться под небольшой процент мамонтов, которые по неведомым причинам упорно сидят на IE 8 и ниже себе же больнее)

Comment: Если быть точным, то, насколько мне известно, последняя версия jQuery с нормальной поддержкой старых IE — это 1.9.1

Comment: заказчик упорно настаивает на ИЕ =/ сайт отображается только в ИЕ10 и в др браузерах. А у нее на 8-ке не открывается, вот и говорит

Comment: >А у нее на 8-ке не открывается, вот и говорит

упоротый заказчик, это, конечно, печально. Но такие вопросы уже вне программистской компетенции. Тут либо вам надо с ней спорить и ругаться, вполне обоснованно требуя корректировки задания (или повышения вашего вознаграждения), либо отказаться от использования последних jQuery